Selenium WebDriver(ChromeDriver) Error When Another Screen Is Open Behind
I am trying to use ChromeDriver. I am using a specific Chrome Profile and I get error when another screen is open behind.
Here is my codeblock works fine when there is no screen behind.
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        options.AddArgument(@"profile-directory=Profile 8");
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

And I tried these codeblocks after my researchs to get over it but still problem continues.
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

And I get this error with this codeblocks.

13.08.2024 16:52:35 session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (SessionNotCreated)

I also have to say that when I try the codeblock below there is no error but I cant use my specific Chrome Profile when I use this.
        options.AddArgument("--headless");

To sum up I want to use my speific profile and there should be open another screen behind when I run it.
